# Android Listview select first ten item

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

In my listview I have a checkbox and when I select the checkbox first 10 rows need to be selected, I did the code like this .. but it is selecting the rest of all rows except the first 10 rows..can anyone help me..what change I need to do here.

```
if (checked)
                  {
                     // Toast.makeText(MyList.this, "Checked.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                      //for(int i=0; i<lv.getChildCount();i++)
                      for(int i=0; i<lv.getAdapter().getCount();i++)
                      {

                          int m = 1;
                          final int firstListItemPosition = lv.getFirstVisiblePosition();

                          //final int firstListItemPosition = (int) lv.getItemAtPosition(m);
                          final int lastListItemPosition = firstListItemPosition + 9;



                          if (i < firstListItemPosition || i > lastListItemPosition ) {
                              View vii = lv.getAdapter().getView(i, null, lv);
                              //return listView.getAdapter().getView(pos, null, listView);
                              CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)vii.findViewById(R.id.selected);
                              cb.setChecked(true);

                          } else {
                              final int childIndex = i - firstListItemPosition;

                              CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)lv.getChildAt(childIndex).findViewById(R.id.selected);
                              cb.setChecked(true);
                          }
                          //Toast.makeText(MyList.this,s, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


                      }
```

Comment: Change your if condition,to  if (i > firstListItemPosition || i <lastListItemPosition )

Comment: The positions may also be incorrect. getFirstVisiblePosition() may or may not be the position you want. If the user selects position 2 then this would be an error! You can save position of each check box to a holder then set/unset checked as user scrolls from that as well so that user can start at any visible checkbox. If user checks a different one, clear and re-set 10.

Comment: No it is not working...

Comment: @CMOSBattery...can u help me..

Answer (score 0):

Your if condition is wrong  `if (i < firstListItemPosition || i > lastListItemPosition )`

change it to

`if (i > firstListItemPosition && i < lastListItemPosition )`

Answer (score 0):

I think the first if thing checks all checkboxes without the ones you wanted.

Try changing the if statement to
i > firstListItemPosition && i < lastListItemPosition

I hope I understand what you want to do correctly.

Comment: Could you then maybe explain what you want to do a bit more?

Comment: I have a list view..and a checkbox. called select 10 rows... When user select that checkbox...first 10 checkbox need to be selected...I just tried with your code but it was crashing then I commented the else condition...at that time..it was not selecting at once..but when I scroll down and came back..I saw the first 9 was get selected..but it was get selecting only after scrolling down.